# Script without jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I have make a script for make columns the same height. This is my script:

```
function equalHeight(group) {
   tallest = 0;
   group.each(function() {
      thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
      if(thisHeight > tallest) {
         tallest = thisHeight;
      }
   });
   group.outerHeight(tallest);
};

equalHeight($(".list-links li"));
```

But i have a problem. In my website, i use jquery ui core. But i want delete that jquery ui. But if I remove the jquery ui. Then this script does not work anymore. Why?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Post a link to a working demo.

Comment: have you written this code in the ui core file by chance? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`.outerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) doesn't work as a setter method as you can see from the documentation. So, this line of code

```
group.outerHeight(tallest);
```

doesn't have any effect without jQuery UI.

jQuery UI wraps `.inner*` and `.outer*` methods and extend them with a setter method as you can see in the excerpt below from [jquery.ui.core.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L166).

```
...
$.fn[ "outer" + name] = function( size, margin ) {
  if ( typeof size !== "number" ) {
    return orig[ "outer" + name ].call( this, size );
  }

  return this.each(function() {
    $( this).css( type, reduce( this, size, true, margin ) + "px" );
  });
};
...
```

These setters, for instance `.outerHeight`, sets the height of the element without the padding, border and optionally the margin.

Answer (score 0):

The script snippet has, at least what I can tell, nothing to do with the UI core (widget interaction). I guess you are calling a UI core widget method somewhere, check error console, probably an undefined function or non-object as soon as you remove the UI core.